# Error in Model.fit() and flow_from_directory()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a facial recognition project. The train folder contains 2 subfolders containing 100 images each. Same for the test folder.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]

train_path = "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Capstone/Train/"
test_path = "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Capstone/Test/"

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='sgd',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
                                   rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

print(training_set.__len__())

r=model.fit(training_set,
            validation_data=test_set,
            epochs=10,
            steps_per_epoch=5,
            validation_steps=32,
            verbose=2)
```

But when doing training_set.**len**(), It outputs 7. Also, I am getting an error in the model. fit(). I can't find a solution to this error. The upper parts of the code are cut. The main issue here is the error from model.fit().

```
Found 200 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 40 images belonging to 2 classes.
7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/Capstone/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    r=model.fit(training_set,
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1108, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1348, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1138, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 231, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 309, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\Capstone\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: This bug is wreaking havoc everywhere. Try downgrade pillow like `pip install pillow==8.2.0` and see if that work.

Comment: It does. Thank you. It has haunted me for the whole day and finally, I find it's a bug.Frustrating...

Comment: I'll post the answer then. Hopefully more people will not be as frustrating as you and me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that comes with new version of `PIL` so downgrading it should do the job.

```
pip install pillow==8.2.0
```